# Oracle OUT SYS_REFCURSOR for JPA entity always null

Tags: java, spring, stored-procedures, plsql

I'm trying to fetch rows using a PLSQL stored procedure, saving them into a JPA entity.
I'm using `ojbdc7`, `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` and `spring-boot 2.2.1`.

This is my procedure:

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY pkg_test
AS
    PROCEDURE getAll(res OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
    IS 
    BEGIN
        OPEN res FOR SELECT * FROM employee;
    END getAll;

END pkg_test;
```

and my entity is:

```
package com.stefanocapra.plsql.entities;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.NamedStoredProcedureQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedStoredProcedureQuery;
import javax.persistence.ParameterMode;
import javax.persistence.StoredProcedureParameter;

import antlr.collections.List;

@Entity
@NamedStoredProcedureQueries({
    @NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
            name = "getAll",
            procedureName = "pkg_test.getAll",
            resultClasses = Employee.class,
            parameters = { 
                    @StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR, type = void.class)
            })
})
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "employee_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "salary")
    private String salary;

    @Column(name = "department_number")
    private String departmentNumber;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }
    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }
    public void setSalary(String salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public String getDepartmentNumber() {
        return departmentNumber;
    }
    public void setDepartmentNumber(String departmentNumber) {
        this.departmentNumber = departmentNumber;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "name = " + this.getFirstName() + 
                " - last name = " + this.getLastName() + 
                " - salary = " + this.getSalary();
    }
}
```

If i call the procedure with:
`List<Employee> employees = repository.getAll();`, the list is always a null object.

I've already checked and the procedure is working.

The employee table is:

- EMPLOYEE_ID NUMBER(19)
- FIRST_NAME VARCHAR2(255)
- LAST_NAME VARCHAR2(255)
- SALARY VARCHAR2(255)
- DEPARTMENT_NUMBER VARCHAR2(255)

Why? What should i do?

Comment: is it resolved? im also facing the same issue..

Answer (score 5):

From what I've seen online on various pages concerning this very thing, hibernate does not support ref cursors. Hibernate gives me this exception:

"REF_CURSOR parameters should be accessed via results; nested exception is org.hibernate.procedure.ParameterMisuseException: REF_CURSOR parameters should be accessed via results"

I was able to get things working by doing something like this.

```
EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager()
StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery("SCHEMA.PROC_NAME", MyObject.class)

query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(1, String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(2, String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
query.registerStoredProcedureParameter(3, MyObject.class, ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR)
query.setParameter(1, "parameter1")
query.setParameter(2, "parameter2")

query.execute()
List<MyObject> results = query.getResultList()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the type of the procedure parameter.

```
@StoredProcedureParameter(mode = ParameterMode.REF_CURSOR, type = ResultSet.class)
```